# Call protected method from child

Tags: java

I have a class with method I want to let the execution to child class. Example:

```
public class Parent {
protected void foo(){return null;}
private void bar(foo());
}
public class Child {
@Override protected void foo(){//do something}
}
```

and I want to call the foo method of child instead of parent in the bar method. It always calls the parent method.
The foo method can not be abstract...

Comment: you could use `super.foo()?` Edit: do you even use inheritance, because your classes do sound like they do, but actually they don´t.

Comment: No, the method i want to call is not in parent class, but in subclass

Comment: @Pink: I can see you have not extended parent class. How you are able to override that method?

Comment: @KrutiPatel Seems like pseudo code :)

Comment: i forgot to write that, sorry

Answer (score 7):

In the `Parent` code, if you do:

```
this.foo();
```

...then provided the object is a `Child` instance, it's the `Child`'s `foo` that will get called. This is an important part of polymorphism. (Assuming, of course, you add `extends Parent` to the `Child` declaration.)

Example: ([live copy on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Ap3UG1))

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new Child().bar();
    }
}
class Parent {
    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("Parent#foo");
    }
    public void bar() {
        this.foo();
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("Child#foo");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Child#foo
```